# How many $Xs$ that makes $\gcd(X,N)\ge M$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I get two integers, $X$ and $N$, ($1\le X \le N$). Let $\gcd(X,N)$ be the greatest common divisor of $X$ and $N$. Given an integer $M$, how many $Xs$ that make  $\gcd(X,N)\ge M$? Are there any efficient algorithms that can solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess $N$ is fixed, too, that is "Given integers $M$ and $N$, how many ..."?

Answer (score 2):

[Corrected in response to a comment]

If $d$ divides $n$, then $$\#\{x:1\le x\le n,\gcd(x,n)=d\}=\phi(n/d)$$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function, so the number you are after is $$\sum_{d\mid n,d\ge M}\phi(n/d)$$ How efficient this is depends on things like how efficiently you can factor $n$ --- I don't see any way to do the calculation, if you can't factor $n$.

Comment: I don't understand clearly. If n=6,M=1, from your formula I can get 6+3+2+1=12. But the correct answer is 6.